# Setting up Reverse DNS Zone BIND9 Ubuntu 13.10 Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I am trying to configure a reverse DNS zone on my new dedicated server. I have tried several things but for some reason i cannot get my reverse zone to properly resolve.

When checking my dns, i get Could not find reverse address for my.masked.ip (my.masked.ip.in-addr.arpa.). PTR record(s) for the address could not be found in the .arpa-zone. (ip6.arpa. for IPv6 addresses and in-addr.arpa. for IPv4).

Here is my reverse zone.

```
 @ IN SOA ns1.domain.com. support.domain.com. (
                    2013120101
                    28800 
                    604800
                    604800
                    86400 
)

                IN    NS     ns1.domain.com.
                IN    NS     ns2.domain.com.
                IN    PTR    Domain.com.
  ns1           IN    A       Ip
  ns2           IN    A       2ip
```

Bind9 && Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Did your provider actually delegate the reverse DNS to you?

Comment: yes i believe so. I will check now. Is my dns record correct?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reverse DNS delegation to you here. Contact your server provider for information on setting up reverse DNS.

Comment: How are you able to tell?

Comment: I just looked up one of your IP addresses with `dig -x 208.52.168.92`.

Comment: Is there a way around it if is not delegated. Trying not to have any errors.

Comment: You need to contact Broadriver. There's nothing _we_ can do for you right now.

Comment: thanks, got in touch with my dedicated company. For some reason the ip addresses were not configured properly. I should have access here in a bit. Does the reverse record look okay when it is properly delegated?

Comment: Their TTL is 1800 so allow 30 minutes _after_ they say they've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange reverse zone.  I'd expect to see some of the following:

- `$ORIGIN 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.` (replace with your IP and put before PTR records but not other records).  This indicates context for the PTR records.
- Some PTR records for IPs in your subnet, such as `1 IN PTR host.example.net.`.
- An additional rDNS zone with the applicable entries for IPv6

If you are using DDNS from dhcpd, you can get away without specifying any of the PTR records yourself.

If this reverse zone is for only one delegated IP address, you can ignore that; your zone will work in that case.  However, you do need the delegation.

To test before you get the delegation, you can use dig.  Specify `dig -x @192.0.2.1 192.0.2.2` where 192.0.2.1 is your DNS server and 192.0.2.2 is the IP with rDNS (it's OK if they are the same).  You should get `IN PTR example.net.`, given your example data, assuming named.conf is also correct.